# Vim Syntax Highlight for Configuration Files

Tags: linux, vim

The vim version on my faculty cluster has a great feature in highlighting the syntax for Linux standard configuration files (like /etc/network/interfaces or httpd.conf).

I've tried a lot of settings and options in the way to obtain the same behavior, but nothing helps.

Any ideas?

Thank you! :)

Comment: If you can detail what you tried it could be an help for the reply.

Comment: I tried to enable syntax highlight, update vim, install it from multiple sources that was promising a very complete addons stack to be included.

Comment: did you tried `syntax on` in your ~/.vimrc ?

Comment: Possibly wider vi audience at http://vi.stackexchange.com

Comment: @dervishe you should submit that as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Put: `syntax on` in your `~/.vimrc` file

Comment: Already did that. It dosen't work for as much files as the one on the faculty cloud.

Comment: You can look into your `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax` directory. Here you can find the coloration syntax file for each supported format. Perhaps some are missing.